# Can SO's Slack integration be enabled without the im:history permission?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, slack

The Stack Overflow for Teams Slack integration requires a number of Slack permissions and scopes.   One of these is im:history.  Can the integration be enabled without this?  If so, what features does it limit or eliminate?  If not, why is it necessary?